Partially italicising manual labels in legends in ggplot
I would like to specify colours and labels manually to a grouped line graph in ggplot. Extra degree of difficulty is that I want to partially italicise the labels. For exmple in the following I would like the n's to be italicised but no other part of the label.
data.frame(out = c(seq(0,1,.1), seq(0,0.5,.05), seq(0,0.1,.01)),
           time = seq(0,50,5),
           group = factor(rep(letters[1:3],each=11))) -> d

# manually changing colour and labels
ggplot(data = d,
       mapping = aes(x = time, 
                     y = out,
                     colour = group)) +
       geom_line() +
       scale_colour_manual(labels = c("All (*n*=730)",
                                      "0 days (*n*=538)",
                                      "1-9 days (*n*=150)"),
                           values = c("#440154",
                                      "#31688E",
                                      "#35B779"))


The colours come out the way I would like and the legend is relabelled, but the n's remain stubbornly unitalicised. Obviously I need more than some half-hearted latex (my feeble *'s). There is plenty out there on how to fully italicise labels but not partial.
Any help much appreciated.

The answers in the duplicate link are also applicable to labels.
